# Failed to save forwarding and transfer options : Missing file

Tags: dns, transfer, forwarding, webmin, bind9

I am trying to configure Forwarding and Transfers for Global forwarding and zone transfer options via Webmin.

It gives me the following output: Failed to save forwarding and transfer options : Missing file to read at bind8::./bind8-lib.pl line 391.

Has anyone encountered this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by removing the Bind Module from Webmin and checking the "Remove from users and reset access control settings?" option. I also purged bind in the terminal on the server. I then installed the module and re downloaded the packages again through Webmin and it is now working fine.